# Galen framework Null pointer exception and FileNotFoundException

Tags: exception, testing, layout, command-line, galen

this is my galen command for gelya1.gspec file

D:\Galen\Project1>galen check gelya1.gspec \ --url http://samples.galenframework.com/tutorial1/tutorial1.html  \ --size 640x480  \ --htmlreport .

This is my gelya1.gspec file
'
@objects
    header              id      header

= Main section =
    header:
        height 40to 120px

'

This is my error logs

## Test: gelya1.gspec

check  gelya1.gspec \ --url http://samples.galenframework.com/tutorial1/tutorial1.html \ --size 640x480 \ --htmlreport .
java.lang.NullPointerException

## Test: \

check  gelya1.gspec \ --url http://samples.galenframework.com/tutorial1/tutorial1.html \ --size 640x480 \ --htmlreport .
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \ (The system cannot find the path specified)

Suite status: FAIL
Total tests: 4
Total failed tests: 3
Total failures: 3
There were failures in galen tests
D:\Galen\Project1> `

Firefox browser is getting launched when I run this command, not sure why these exceptions are coming.

Comment: I've created a PR for this issue, see https://github.com/galenframework/galen/pull/396